# Rails - How to display SQL values in a OCIError?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, oracle, exception

I'm using Ruby on Rails with Oracle, using the gem `ruby-oci8`. Sometimes things go wrong and we get a SQL error, be it because of a bad grouping or a PK violation. The thing is, it never shows the actual values that the query was trying to run.

Example error output (getting the sql from `e.original_exception.sql`, where `e` is the raised Exception, of course):

```
"INSERT INTO \"VERSIONS\" (\"CREATED_AT\", \"EVENT\", \"ID\", \"ITEM_ID\", \"ITEM_TYPE\", \"OBJECT\", \"WHODUNNIT\")
VALUES (:a1, :a2, :a3, :a4, :a5, :a6, :a7)"
```

**The question is:** How do I make it show the actual values instead of ":a1, :a2, etc..."?

ps: The full exception message for this specific error was:

```
#<ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: OCIError: ORA-00001: unique constraint ({redated_db_name}.VERSIONS_PK) violated: INSERT INTO "VERSIONS" ("CREATED_AT", "EVENT", "ID", "ITEM_ID", "ITEM_TYPE", "OBJECT", "WHODUNNIT") VALUES (:a1, :a2, :a3, :a4, :a5, :a6, :a7)>
```

EDIT: This might also apply to errors on other databases as well, like MySQL. Can someone please confirm this?

Comment: Oracle doesn't substitute the parameter values into the SQL string. Only the procedure which invoked the SQL statement knows what the bound values are, so the calling procedure is responsible for displaying the parameter values if that's needed. I suggest you do this in your exception handler. Best of luck.

Comment: I can't do that because it's PaperTrail who's invoking it. I'd need to do some deep monkey patching to debug this, but I'll look into it, thank you